# Trouble getting POST to work with cURL, coming through as a GET

Tags: php, curl

I am working on some missions on Security Override and hackthissite.  I would like to make some automation to get images/clues problematically.  So I need to log into the site using php/cURL.  There are many sites with how other folks did it, and I have tried most of them.  The probelem is the post data is not being send.  In fact, the whole http packet is not showing in httpfox and zap as a POST at all, its going through as a GET.

```
$log = "admin";
$password = "password";
$redirect = "wp-admin/";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.pridegrimm.com/wp-login.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'log='.urlencode($log).'&pwd='.urlencode($password).'&redirect_to='.urlencode($redirect));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.3) Gecko/20070309 Firefox/2.0.0.3");
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Tamperdata is showing it as a get and no post parameters.  I surely hope I am not overlooking something very silly.  Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?  This code works for many other folks.

When I debug the program, $ch initializes to "resource id='2' type='curl'", but never changes.  I assume it should while doing the curl_setopt statements are running. Maybe I have a setting wrong or something.

running echo function_exists('curl_version'); yields 1.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/z6abdrfnr1weuoa/AAASI3QCGNcwyfjAJDxDgQc4a?dl=0

I'm using Zend eclipse, with php 5.6.  xampp apache server.  Here is phpinfo

```
PHP logo
PHP Version 5.5.19

System  Windows NT PDSLAPTOP-PC 6.1 build 7601 (Windows 7 Ultimate Edition Service Pack 1) i586
Build Date  Nov 12 2014 12:29:42
Compiler    MSVC11 (Visual C++ 2012)
Architecture    x86
Configure Command   cscript /nologo configure.js "--enable-snapshot-build" "--disable-isapi" "--enable-debug-pack" "--without-mssql" "--without-pdo-mssql" "--without-pi3web" "--with-pdo-oci=C:\php-sdk\oracle\x86\instantclient10\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8=C:\php-sdk\oracle\x86\instantclient10\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8-11g=C:\php-sdk\oracle\x86\instantclient11\sdk,shared" "--enable-object-out-dir=../obj/" "--enable-com-dotnet=shared" "--with-mcrypt=static" "--disable-static-analyze" "--with-pgo"
Server API  Apache 2.0 Handler
Virtual Directory Support   enabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File   C:\xampp\php\php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files     (none)
Additional .ini files parsed    (none)
PHP API     20121113
PHP Extension   20121212
Zend Extension  220121212
Zend Extension Build    API220121212,TS,VC11
PHP Extension Build     API20121212,TS,VC11
Debug Build     no
Thread Safety   enabled
Zend Signal Handling    disabled
Zend Memory Manager     enabled
Zend Multibyte Support  provided by mbstring
IPv6 Support    enabled
DTrace Support  disabled
Registered PHP Streams  php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, zip, compress.zlib, compress.bzip2, https, ftps, phar
Registered Stream Socket Transports tcp, udp, ssl, sslv3, sslv2, tls
Registered Stream Filters   convert.iconv.*, mcrypt.*, mdecrypt.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, dechunk, zlib.*, bzip2.*

Zend logo This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by Derick Rethans

Configuration
apache2handler
Apache Version  Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.5.19
Apache API Version  20120211
Server Administrator    postmaster@localhost
Hostname:Port   localhost:8080
Max Requests    Per Child: 0 - Keep Alive: on - Max Per Connection: 100
Timeouts    Connection: 300 - Keep-Alive: 5
Virtual Server  No
Server Root     C:/xampp/apache
Loaded Modules  core mod_win32 mpm_winnt http_core mod_so mod_access_compat mod_actions mod_alias mod_allowmethods mod_asis mod_auth_basic mod_authn_core mod_authn_file mod_authz_core mod_authz_groupfile mod_authz_host mod_authz_user mod_autoindex mod_cgi mod_dav_lock mod_dir mod_env mod_headers mod_include mod_info mod_isapi mod_log_config mod_cache_disk mod_mime mod_negotiation mod_proxy mod_proxy_ajp mod_rewrite mod_setenvif mod_socache_shmcb mod_ssl mod_status mod_version mod_php5

Directive   Local Value Master Value
engine  1   1
last_modified   0   0
xbithack    0   0

Apache Environment
Variable    Value
MIBDIRS     C:/xampp/php/extras/mibs
MYSQL_HOME  \xampp\mysql\bin
OPENSSL_CONF    C:/xampp/apache/bin/openssl.cnf
PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR    \xampp\php
PHPRC   \xampp\php
TMP     \xampp\tmp
HTTP_HOST   localhost:8080
HTTP_USER_AGENT     Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0
HTTP_ACCEPT     text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE    en-US,en;q=0.5
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING    gzip, deflate
HTTP_CONNECTION     keep-alive
PATH    C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Network Monitor 3\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Universal Extractor;C:\Program Files (x86)\Universal Extractor\bin;C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Network Monitor 3\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Universal Extractor;C:\Program Files (x86)\Universal Extractor\bin;;C:\Python34;
SystemRoot  C:\Windows
COMSPEC     C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
PATHEXT     .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
WINDIR  C:\Windows
SERVER_SIGNATURE    <address>Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.5.19 Server at localhost Port 8080</address>
SERVER_SOFTWARE     Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.5.19
SERVER_NAME     localhost
SERVER_ADDR     ::1
SERVER_PORT     8080
REMOTE_ADDR     ::1
DOCUMENT_ROOT   C:/xampp/htdocs
REQUEST_SCHEME  http
CONTEXT_PREFIX  no value
CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT   C:/xampp/htdocs
SERVER_ADMIN    postmaster@localhost
SCRIPT_FILENAME     C:/xampp/htdocs/firstphp/index.php
REMOTE_PORT     53939
GATEWAY_INTERFACE   CGI/1.1
SERVER_PROTOCOL     HTTP/1.1
REQUEST_METHOD  GET
QUERY_STRING    no value
REQUEST_URI     /firstphp/index.php
SCRIPT_NAME     /firstphp/index.php

HTTP Headers Information
HTTP Request Headers
HTTP Request    GET /firstphp/index.php HTTP/1.1
Host    localhost:8080
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language     en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding     gzip, deflate
Connection  keep-alive
HTTP Response Headers
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.5.19

bcmath
BCMath support  enabled

Directive   Local Value Master Value
bcmath.scale    0   0

bz2
BZip2 Support   Enabled
Stream Wrapper support  compress.bzip2://
Stream Filter support   bzip2.decompress, bzip2.compress
BZip2 Version   1.0.6, 6-Sept-2010

calendar
Calendar support    enabled

Core
PHP Version     5.5.19

Directive   Local Value Master Value
allow_url_fopen On  On
allow_url_include   Off Off
always_populate_raw_post_data   Off Off
arg_separator.input &   &
arg_separator.output    &   &
asp_tags    Off Off
auto_append_file    no value    no value
auto_globals_jit    On  On
auto_prepend_file   no value    no value
browscap    C:\xampp\php\extras\browscap.ini    C:\xampp\php\extras\browscap.ini
default_charset no value    no value
default_mimetype    text/html   text/html
disable_classes no value    no value
disable_functions   no value    no value
display_errors  On  On
display_startup_errors  On  On
doc_root    no value    no value
docref_ext  no value    no value
docref_root no value    no value
enable_dl   On  On
enable_post_data_reading    On  On
error_append_string no value    no value
error_log   C:\xampp\php\logs\php_error_log C:\xampp\php\logs\php_error_log
error_prepend_string    no value    no value
error_reporting 22527   22527
exit_on_timeout Off Off
expose_php  On  On
extension_dir   C:\xampp\php\ext    C:\xampp\php\ext
file_uploads    On  On
highlight.comment   #FF8000 #FF8000
highlight.default   #0000BB #0000BB
highlight.html  #000000 #000000
highlight.keyword   #007700 #007700
highlight.string    #DD0000 #DD0000
html_errors On  On
ignore_repeated_errors  Off Off
ignore_repeated_source  Off Off
ignore_user_abort   Off Off
implicit_flush  On  On
include_path    .;C:\xampp\php\PEAR .;C:\xampp\php\PEAR
log_errors  On  On
log_errors_max_len  1024    1024
mail.add_x_header   Off Off
mail.force_extra_parameters no value    no value
mail.log    no value    no value
max_execution_time  30  30
max_file_uploads    20  20
max_input_nesting_level 64  64
max_input_time  60  60
max_input_vars  1000    1000
memory_limit    128M    128M
open_basedir    no value    no value
output_buffering    0   0
output_handler  no value    no value
post_max_size   8M  8M
precision   14  14
realpath_cache_size 16K 16K
realpath_cache_ttl  120 120
register_argc_argv  Off Off
report_memleaks On  On
report_zend_debug   On  On
request_order   GP  GP
sendmail_from   no value    no value
sendmail_path   C:\xampp\mailtodisk\mailtodisk.exe  C:\xampp\mailtodisk\mailtodisk.exe
serialize_precision 100 100
short_open_tag  Off Off
SMTP    localhost   localhost
smtp_port   25  25
sql.safe_mode   Off Off
sys_temp_dir    no value    no value
track_errors    On  On
unserialize_callback_func   no value    no value
upload_max_filesize 2M  2M
upload_tmp_dir  C:\xampp\tmp    C:\xampp\tmp
user_dir    no value    no value
user_ini.cache_ttl  300 300
user_ini.filename   .user.ini   .user.ini
variables_order GPCS    GPCS
windows.show_crt_warning    Off Off
xmlrpc_error_number 0   0
xmlrpc_errors   Off Off
zend.detect_unicode On  On
zend.enable_gc  On  On
zend.multibyte  Off Off
zend.script_encoding    no value    no value

ctype
ctype functions     enabled

curl
cURL support    enabled
cURL Information    7.39.0
Age     3
Features
AsynchDNS   Yes
CharConv    No
Debug   No
GSS-Negotiate   No
IDN     Yes
IPv6    Yes
krb4    No
Largefile   Yes
libz    Yes
NTLM    Yes
NTLMWB  No
SPNEGO  Yes
SSL     Yes
SSPI    Yes
TLS-SRP     No
Protocols   dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps, ldap, pop3, pop3s, rtsp, scp, sftp, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp
Host    i386-pc-win32
SSL Version     OpenSSL/1.0.1i
ZLib Version    1.2.7.3
libSSH Version  libssh2/1.4.3

date
date/time support   enabled
"Olson" Timezone Database Version   2014.9
Timezone Database   internal
Default timezone    Europe/Berlin

Directive   Local Value Master Value
date.default_latitude   31.7667 31.7667
date.default_longitude  35.2333 35.2333
date.sunrise_zenith 90.583333   90.583333
date.sunset_zenith  90.583333   90.583333
date.timezone   Europe/Berlin   Europe/Berlin

dom
DOM/XML     enabled
DOM/XML API Version     20031129
libxml Version  2.9.1
HTML Support    enabled
XPath Support   enabled
XPointer Support    enabled
Schema Support  enabled
RelaxNG Support     enabled

ereg
Regex Library   Bundled library enabled

exif
EXIF Support    enabled
EXIF Version    1.4 $Id: 637ebf9289b40d157fdf8edcdddeb3d907b28d9b $
Supported EXIF Version  0220
Supported filetypes     JPEG,TIFF

Directive   Local Value Master Value
exif.decode_jis_intel   JIS JIS
exif.decode_jis_motorola    JIS JIS
exif.decode_unicode_intel   UCS-2LE UCS-2LE
exif.decode_unicode_motorola    UCS-2BE UCS-2BE
exif.encode_jis no value    no value
exif.encode_unicode ISO-8859-15 ISO-8859-15

filter
Input Validation and Filtering  enabled
Revision    $Id: 4d3899e089e6e45b157975ceef2ac7deb6e9d762 $

Directive   Local Value Master Value
filter.default  unsafe_raw  unsafe_raw
filter.default_flags    no value    no value

ftp
FTP support     enabled

gd
GD Support  enabled
GD Version  bundled (2.1.0 compatible)
FreeType Support    enabled
FreeType Linkage    with freetype
FreeType Version    2.4.10
GIF Read Support    enabled
GIF Create Support  enabled
JPEG Support    enabled
libJPEG Version     9 compatible
PNG Support     enabled
libPNG Version  1.5.18
WBMP Support    enabled
XPM Support     enabled
libXpm Version  30411
XBM Support     enabled
WebP Support    enabled

Directive   Local Value Master Value
gd.jpeg_ignore_warning  0   0

gettext
GetText Support     enabled

hash
hash support    enabled
Hashing Engines     md2 md4 md5 sha1 sha224 sha256 sha384 sha512 ripemd128 ripemd160 ripemd256 ripemd320 whirlpool tiger128,3 tiger160,3 tiger192,3 tiger128,4 tiger160,4 tiger192,4 snefru snefru256 gost adler32 crc32 crc32b fnv132 fnv164 joaat haval128,3 haval160,3 haval192,3 haval224,3 haval256,3 haval128,4 haval160,4 haval192,4 haval224,4 haval256,4 haval128,5 haval160,5 haval192,5 haval224,5 haval256,5

iconv
iconv support   enabled
iconv implementation    "libiconv"
iconv library version   1.14

Directive   Local Value Master Value
iconv.input_encoding    ISO-8859-1  ISO-8859-1
iconv.internal_encoding ISO-8859-1  ISO-8859-1
iconv.output_encoding   ISO-8859-1  ISO-8859-1

json
json support    enabled
json version    1.2.1

libxml
libXML support  active
libXML Compiled Version     2.9.1
libXML Loaded Version   20901
libXML streams  enabled

mbstring
Multibyte Support   enabled
Multibyte string engine     libmbfl
HTTP input encoding translation     disabled
libmbfl version     1.3.2

mbstring extension makes use of "streamable kanji code filter and converter", which is distributed under the GNU Lesser General Public License version 2.1.

Multibyte (japanese) regex support  enabled
Multibyte regex (oniguruma) version     5.9.2

Directive   Local Value Master Value
mbstring.detect_order   no value    no value
mbstring.encoding_translation   Off Off
mbstring.func_overload  0   0
mbstring.http_input pass    pass
mbstring.http_output    pass    pass
mbstring.http_output_conv_mimetypes ^(text/|application/xhtml\+xml) ^(text/|application/xhtml\+xml)
mbstring.internal_encoding  no value    no value
mbstring.language   neutral neutral
mbstring.strict_detection   Off Off
mbstring.substitute_character   no value    no value

mcrypt
mcrypt support  enabled
mcrypt_filter support   enabled
Version     2.5.8
Api No  20021217
Supported ciphers   cast-128 gost rijndael-128 twofish cast-256 loki97 rijndael-192 saferplus wake blowfish-compat des rijndael-256 serpent xtea blowfish enigma rc2 tripledes arcfour
Supported modes     cbc cfb ctr ecb ncfb nofb ofb stream

Directive   Local Value Master Value
mcrypt.algorithms_dir   no value    no value
mcrypt.modes_dir    no value    no value

mhash
MHASH support   Enabled
MHASH API Version   Emulated Support

mysql
MySQL Support   enabled
Active Persistent Links     0
Active Links    0
Client API version  mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: bf9ad53b11c9a57efdb1057292d73b928b8c5c77 $

Directive   Local Value Master Value
mysql.allow_local_infile    On  On
mysql.allow_persistent  On  On
mysql.connect_timeout   3   3
mysql.default_host  no value    no value
mysql.default_password  no value    no value
mysql.default_port  3306    3306
mysql.default_socket    MySQL   MySQL
mysql.default_user  no value    no value
mysql.max_links Unlimited   Unlimited
mysql.max_persistent    Unlimited   Unlimited
mysql.trace_mode    Off Off

mysqli
MysqlI Support  enabled
Client API library version  mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: bf9ad53b11c9a57efdb1057292d73b928b8c5c77 $
Active Persistent Links     0
Inactive Persistent Links   0
Active Links    0

Directive   Local Value Master Value
mysqli.allow_local_infile   On  On
mysqli.allow_persistent On  On
mysqli.default_host no value    no value
mysqli.default_port 3306    3306
mysqli.default_pw   no value    no value
mysqli.default_socket   MySQL   MySQL
mysqli.default_user no value    no value
mysqli.max_links    Unlimited   Unlimited
mysqli.max_persistent   Unlimited   Unlimited
mysqli.reconnect    Off Off

mysqlnd
mysqlnd enabled
Version     mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: bf9ad53b11c9a57efdb1057292d73b928b8c5c77 $
Compression     supported
core SSL    supported
extended SSL    not supported
Command buffer size     4096
Read buffer size    32768
Read timeout    31536000
Collecting statistics   Yes
Collecting memory statistics    No
Tracing     n/a
Loaded plugins  mysqlnd,debug_trace,auth_plugin_mysql_native_password,auth_plugin_mysql_clear_password
API Extensions  mysql,mysqli,pdo_mysql

mysqlnd statistics  
bytes_sent  0
bytes_received  0
packets_sent    0
packets_received    0
protocol_overhead_in    0
protocol_overhead_out   0
bytes_received_ok_packet    0
bytes_received_eof_packet   0
bytes_received_rset_header_packet   0
bytes_received_rset_field_meta_packet   0
bytes_received_rset_row_packet  0
bytes_received_prepare_response_packet  0
bytes_received_change_user_packet   0
packets_sent_command    0
packets_received_ok     0
packets_received_eof    0
packets_received_rset_header    0
packets_received_rset_field_meta    0
packets_received_rset_row   0
packets_received_prepare_response   0
packets_received_change_user    0
result_set_queries  0
non_result_set_queries  0
no_index_used   0
bad_index_used  0
slow_queries    0
buffered_sets   0
unbuffered_sets     0
ps_buffered_sets    0
ps_unbuffered_sets  0
flushed_normal_sets     0
flushed_ps_sets     0
ps_prepared_never_executed  0
ps_prepared_once_executed   0
rows_fetched_from_server_normal     0
rows_fetched_from_server_ps     0
rows_buffered_from_client_normal    0
rows_buffered_from_client_ps    0
rows_fetched_from_client_normal_buffered    0
rows_fetched_from_client_normal_unbuffered  0
rows_fetched_from_client_ps_buffered    0
rows_fetched_from_client_ps_unbuffered  0
rows_fetched_from_client_ps_cursor  0
rows_affected_normal    0
rows_affected_ps    0
rows_skipped_normal     0
rows_skipped_ps     0
copy_on_write_saved     0
copy_on_write_performed     0
command_buffer_too_small    0
connect_success     0
connect_failure     0
connection_reused   0
reconnect   0
pconnect_success    0
active_connections  0
active_persistent_connections   0
explicit_close  0
implicit_close  0
disconnect_close    0
in_middle_of_command_close  0
explicit_free_result    0
implicit_free_result    0
explicit_stmt_close     0
implicit_stmt_close     0
mem_emalloc_count   0
mem_emalloc_amount  0
mem_ecalloc_count   0
mem_ecalloc_amount  0
mem_erealloc_count  0
mem_erealloc_amount     0
mem_efree_count     0
mem_efree_amount    0
mem_malloc_count    0
mem_malloc_amount   0
mem_calloc_count    0
mem_calloc_amount   0
mem_realloc_count   0
mem_realloc_amount  0
mem_free_count  0
mem_free_amount     0
mem_estrndup_count  0
mem_strndup_count   0
mem_estndup_count   0
mem_strdup_count    0
proto_text_fetched_null     0
proto_text_fetched_bit  0
proto_text_fetched_tinyint  0
proto_text_fetched_short    0
proto_text_fetched_int24    0
proto_text_fetched_int  0
proto_text_fetched_bigint   0
proto_text_fetched_decimal  0
proto_text_fetched_float    0
proto_text_fetched_double   0
proto_text_fetched_date     0
proto_text_fetched_year     0
proto_text_fetched_time     0
proto_text_fetched_datetime     0
proto_text_fetched_timestamp    0
proto_text_fetched_string   0
proto_text_fetched_blob     0
proto_text_fetched_enum     0
proto_text_fetched_set  0
proto_text_fetched_geometry     0
proto_text_fetched_other    0
proto_binary_fetched_null   0
proto_binary_fetched_bit    0
proto_binary_fetched_tinyint    0
proto_binary_fetched_short  0
proto_binary_fetched_int24  0
proto_binary_fetched_int    0
proto_binary_fetched_bigint     0
proto_binary_fetched_decimal    0
proto_binary_fetched_float  0
proto_binary_fetched_double     0
proto_binary_fetched_date   0
proto_binary_fetched_year   0
proto_binary_fetched_time   0
proto_binary_fetched_datetime   0
proto_binary_fetched_timestamp  0
proto_binary_fetched_string     0
proto_binary_fetched_blob   0
proto_binary_fetched_enum   0
proto_binary_fetched_set    0
proto_binary_fetched_geometry   0
proto_binary_fetched_other  0
init_command_executed_count     0
init_command_failed_count   0
com_quit    0
com_init_db     0
com_query   0
com_field_list  0
com_create_db   0
com_drop_db     0
com_refresh     0
com_shutdown    0
com_statistics  0
com_process_info    0
com_connect     0
com_process_kill    0
com_debug   0
com_ping    0
com_time    0
com_delayed_insert  0
com_change_user     0
com_binlog_dump     0
com_table_dump  0
com_connect_out     0
com_register_slave  0
com_stmt_prepare    0
com_stmt_execute    0
com_stmt_send_long_data     0
com_stmt_close  0
com_stmt_reset  0
com_stmt_set_option     0
com_stmt_fetch  0
com_deamon  0
bytes_received_real_data_normal     0
bytes_received_real_data_ps     0

odbc
ODBC Support    enabled
Active Persistent Links     0
Active Links    0
ODBC library    Win32

Directive   Local Value Master Value
odbc.allow_persistent   On  On
odbc.check_persistent   On  On
odbc.default_cursortype Static cursor   Static cursor
odbc.default_db no value    no value
odbc.default_pw no value    no value
odbc.default_user   no value    no value
odbc.defaultbinmode return as is    return as is
odbc.defaultlrl return up to 4096 bytes return up to 4096 bytes
odbc.max_links  Unlimited   Unlimited
odbc.max_persistent Unlimited   Unlimited

openssl
OpenSSL support     enabled
OpenSSL Library Version     OpenSSL 1.0.1i 6 Aug 2014
OpenSSL Header Version  OpenSSL 1.0.1i 6 Aug 2014

pcre
PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) Support  enabled
PCRE Library Version    8.34 2013-12-15

Directive   Local Value Master Value
pcre.backtrack_limit    1000000 1000000
pcre.recursion_limit    100000  100000

PDO
PDO support enabled
PDO drivers     mysql, sqlite

pdo_mysql
PDO Driver for MySQL    enabled
Client API version  mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: bf9ad53b11c9a57efdb1057292d73b928b8c5c77 $

pdo_sqlite
PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x   enabled
SQLite Library  3.8.4.3

Phar
Phar: PHP Archive support   enabled
Phar EXT version    2.0.2
Phar API version    1.1.1
SVN revision    $Id: cc0fad28eb9ea42466f756c3b5fc22c764e32690 $
Phar-based phar archives    enabled
Tar-based phar archives     enabled
ZIP-based phar archives     enabled
gzip compression    enabled
bzip2 compression   enabled
OpenSSL support     enabled

Phar based on pear/PHP_Archive, original concept by Davey Shafik.
Phar fully realized by Gregory Beaver and Marcus Boerger.
Portions of tar implementation Copyright (c) 2003-2009 Tim Kientzle.

Directive   Local Value Master Value
phar.cache_list no value    no value
phar.readonly   On  On
phar.require_hash   On  On

Reflection
Reflection  enabled
Version     $Id: 95b780d3f0d017feba96a5c35cca9541186114ad $

session
Session Support     enabled
Registered save handlers    files user
Registered serializer handlers  php_serialize php php_binary wddx

Directive   Local Value Master Value
session.auto_start  Off Off
session.cache_expire    180 180
session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache
session.cookie_domain   no value    no value
session.cookie_httponly Off Off
session.cookie_lifetime 0   0
session.cookie_path /   /
session.cookie_secure   Off Off
session.entropy_file    no value    no value
session.entropy_length  0   0
session.gc_divisor  1000    1000
session.gc_maxlifetime  1440    1440
session.gc_probability  1   1
session.hash_bits_per_character 5   5
session.hash_function   0   0
session.name    PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
session.referer_check   no value    no value
session.save_handler    files   files
session.save_path   C:\xampp\tmp    C:\xampp\tmp
session.serialize_handler   php php
session.upload_progress.cleanup On  On
session.upload_progress.enabled On  On
session.upload_progress.freq    1%  1%
session.upload_progress.min_freq    1   1
session.upload_progress.name    PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
session.upload_progress.prefix  upload_progress_    upload_progress_
session.use_cookies On  On
session.use_only_cookies    Off Off
session.use_strict_mode Off Off
session.use_trans_sid   0   0

SimpleXML
Simplexml support   enabled
Revision    $Id: a915862ec47f9589309acc4996ca8f6179788746 $
Schema support  enabled

soap
Soap Client     enabled
Soap Server     enabled

Directive   Local Value Master Value
soap.wsdl_cache 1   1
soap.wsdl_cache_dir /tmp    /tmp
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled 1   1
soap.wsdl_cache_limit   5   5
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl 86400   86400

sockets
Sockets Support     enabled

SPL
SPL support enabled
Interfaces  Countable, OuterIterator, RecursiveIterator, SeekableIterator, SplObserver, SplSubject
Classes     AppendIterator, ArrayIterator, ArrayObject, BadFunctionCallException, BadMethodCallException, CachingIterator, CallbackFilterIterator, DirectoryIterator, DomainException, EmptyIterator, FilesystemIterator, FilterIterator, GlobIterator, InfiniteIterator, InvalidArgumentException, IteratorIterator, LengthException, LimitIterator, LogicException, MultipleIterator, NoRewindIterator, OutOfBoundsException, OutOfRangeException, OverflowException, ParentIterator, RangeException, RecursiveArrayIterator, RecursiveCachingIterator, RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator, RecursiveDirectoryIterator, RecursiveFilterIterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator, RecursiveRegexIterator, RecursiveTreeIterator, RegexIterator, RuntimeException, SplDoublyLinkedList, SplFileInfo, SplFileObject, SplFixedArray, SplHeap, SplMinHeap, SplMaxHeap, SplObjectStorage, SplPriorityQueue, SplQueue, SplStack, SplTempFileObject, UnderflowException, UnexpectedValueException

sqlite3
SQLite3 support enabled
SQLite3 module version  0.7-dev
SQLite Library  3.8.4.3

Directive   Local Value Master Value
sqlite3.extension_dir   no value    no value

standard
Dynamic Library Support     enabled
Path to sendmail    C:\xampp\mailtodisk\mailtodisk.exe

Directive   Local Value Master Value
assert.active   1   1
assert.bail 0   0
assert.callback no value    no value
assert.quiet_eval   0   0
assert.warning  1   1
auto_detect_line_endings    0   0
default_socket_timeout  60  60
from    no value    no value
url_rewriter.tags   a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry
user_agent  no value    no value
```

Answer (score 1):

1. The httpfox debug info (in dropbox url) is "incorrect".

From your snapshot you are catching the request from your browser to your server: "http://localhost:8080/firstphp/index.php", this one is "GET" for sure.

You need debug the request which curl send out (http://www.pridegrimm.com/wp-login.php). This is a **server to server** request. To catch the curl request, suggest use "Fiddler" debug tool with CURLOPT_PROXYPORT / CURLOPT_PROXY in PHP code.

2. As @zeflex mentioned, http_build_query is better than manually build the post data.
3. Check the result "var_dump($resut);" and "var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));" may help debbugging this issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($post));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));
```

$post should be an associative array like:

```
$post = array(
'log' => $log,
'pwd' => $password,
...);
```

Not sure if you need `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);` I don't have this in my code.